# How are adrenaline points used?

Tags: the-witcher-3

AP accumulates during combat however I have yet to see a specific use for them. I see no weapons, signs, or skills that state the need for them. I do see throughout application of the aforementioned that AP will increase during combat as well as drain out of combat.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the article [Adrenaline - how to gain it and what is it used for](https://guides.gamepressure.com/thewitcher3/guide.asp?ID=30859):

> Adrenaline on its own doesn't change anything. But it can cooperate with many skills, modifying them or increasing their effectiveness.
>   Most important relations with adrenaline have:
>
> **Undying** skill from the Combat category - Thanks to this skill when you lose all health points you don't die immediately, adrenaline points can be used to keep Geralt alive.
>
> **Rend** skill from the Combat category - Adrenaline points can increase the amount of damage dealt even by 100%.
>
> **Deadly Precision** skill from the Combat category - Adrenaline points increase the percentage chance of instantly killing the opponent.
>
> **Flood of Anger** skill from the Combat category - Having enough adrenaline points allows you to activate the witcher sign on the highest level possible and increase the attack strength.
>
> **Hunter Instincts** skill from the Alchemy category - Having the maximum amount of adrenaline points will increase the damage of critical hits. However, it will work only if an oil effective against a specific monster type has been used.
>
> **Rage management** skill from the Abilities category - It allows you to activate witcher signs even if you don't have enough stamina. Adrenaline points will be consumed instead of the lacking stamina.
>
> **Focus** skill from the Abilities category - One of more interesting skills. Thanks to adrenaline points Geralt can deal more damage and the strength of his signs increase.

Various other sources also mention a general damage increase the more adrenaline you have. From a post on [CD Projekt Red Forum](https://forums.cdprojektred.com/forum/en/the-witcher-series/the-witcher-3-wild-hunt/40316-adrenaline-points-what-for?p=1836220#post1836220) :

> Each point of Adrenaline increases your sword damage by 5% So with 3 Adrenaline points your max sword damage is increased by 15%.

Finally, some skills such as Whirl can be maintained with the use of Adrenaline once Stamina is depleted.

Comment: THANK YOU! very very much, actually. This was more than just an answer this was thorough as they come. My question only arose after sheer desperation and frustration. I apologize if this query was redundant however I created account just for this question. Thank you again Twobe7. I plan to start here first in my gaming confusion or curiosity. Cheers.

Comment: does anyone knows by how much % the focus ability increase attacks?

Answer (score 2):

Game Pressure's description of the adrenaline point usage may very well be the absolute extent of the purpose for AP, however, some players have explained (somewhat vaguely) their usage in *finishing moves*.

According to a couple different posts I've read from various forums (Steam being one), adrenaline points can be used by **holding down** the fast attack *or* strong attack buttons, causing Geralt to execute different 'finishing moves'. By default, these are the left and right mouse buttons.